# json request failed to pass json object to php var_dump is empty

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, post

i want to pass a json object with ajax request in my js page but when i do it, in php i have the $_POST array empty.

javascript page

```
    function invia(cat,subcat)
{
    var tipo = cat.options[cat.selectedIndex].text;
    var sottotipo = subcat.options[subcat.selectedIndex].text;

    var lat = getLatitudine();
    var lon = getLongitudine();     

        $.ajax({    
            type:'POST',                                
            url: "apriSegnalazione.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data : { 
                type: {type: tipo, subtype: sottotipo};
                lat: lat,
                lng: lon
                }           
            }).success(function(data){

                alert( "Data Saved: "+ data);

            });

}
```

and this is my php page

```
<?php  
header('Content-Type: application/json',true);
header('Accept: application/json');

  $tipo = $_POST['type'];    
  $ris = json_decode($tipo,true);
    var_dump($ris);

?>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `;` with `,` from this line,

```
type: {type: tipo, subtype: sottotipo};
```

Should be,

```
type: {type: tipo, subtype: sottotipo},
```

There is an error `SyntaxError: missing } after property list` in your script, and always use tools like mozilla's firebug addon, when you are processing with ajax requests. You can see the above error in firebug's console panel.

Comment: the response in php is empty, this was my problem.

the object type doesn't exists in $_POST

Comment: in $_POST there are 
lat 44.4779266
lng 11.3599224
type[subtype] incidente
type[type] problemi stradali

but how to manage this data in php?

if i try var_dump, i have NULL as response..

Comment: What you want to do with $_POST in php, and what is expected as response from php?

Comment: i want to save this values in mysql or in a local variable and print them.

Comment: Saving the data is ok, but what you meant by "print them"? Do you want to send the result as response, and want to print it using ajax callback?